# Wait until GameCenter score download id complete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, objective-c-blocks, game-center

I would like to download score from GameCenter, but I don't know how to wait, when score is downloaded. When I run this code, it returns null. I think, that method have to wait when `[leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ...` will have score downloaded.

```
- (NSString*) getScore: (NSString*) leaderboardID
{
    __block NSString *score = nil;
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
    {
        leaderboardRequest.identifier = leaderboardID;
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            if (scores != nil)
            {
                int64_t scoreInt = leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore.value;
                score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", scoreInt];

            }
        }];
    }
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code from the completion handler will be called when the operation is complete (on another thread).

You have several options there, you can store the score somewhere and post a notification to notify the main thread that the operation is completed.